# How long do I have to wait for another Massive Mass Outbreak?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

Request 96, "Massive Mass Outbreak in the Fieldlands", requires you to clear three of the individual outbreaks within a Massive Mass Outbreak. I was severely waylaid clearing the first one, and the Massive Mass Outbreak disappeared while I was still clearing the second one, leaving me unable to complete the request.

Talking to Mai, the questgiver, has her suggest going back to Jubilife and waiting for another one to spawn. This I've done, but I've gone out on three excursions now, spanning a few in-game days, and another Massive Mass Outbreak still hasn't spawned. I know that Massive Mass Outbreaks don't start spawning regularly until I've completed the entire "Daybreak" questline, and I'm now starting to get concerned that I may have locked myself out of the questline entirely.

**How much longer do I have to wait before I get another shot at clearing Request 96?** Is there something specific I can do to get the Massive Mass Outbreak to respawn? Or am I at the mercy of RNG?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you can clear the Pokémon from *one* outbreak even if the outbreak has ended.  From this [IGN article](https://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-legends-arceus/Massive_Mass_Outbreaks#How_to_Make_Massive_Mass_Outbreaks_Spawn):

> - However, if the Massive Mass Outbreak disappears while you are in the middle of investigating an outbreak, those particular Pokemon will remain. Clear them, and it will still count, even if the storm had dispersed!

This might suggest a strategy of trying to find 3 of them before it stops raining, *even if* you haven't finished all three.

If you aren't on the same map, though, or if you aren't in the middle of the third outbreak of that particular map, then you will need to respawn it by heading back to Jubilife Village.  You'll get this message from Mai:

[image: Image of Mai saying the outbreak is over]

When you get back to Jubilife Village, if the rainstorm is gone, you'll see no Massive Mass Outbreak; a regular Mass Outbreak doesn't count.

[image: Image of map with no massive mass outbreak]

The next time there is a rainstorm or blizzard, there will be another Massive Mass Outbreak.  The easiest way to force this, rather than going back and forth frequently, is to force the weather *first*.  This can be done by repeatedly resting - I usually go on a cycle Morning -> Midday -> Evening -> Morning (repeat), but it's possible this isn't the most efficient.  Once you wake up to a rainstorm (the cloud-lightning bolt icon), you should go back to Jubilife Village immediately, and then turn around and come back; as long as the weather doesn't change in the short time for the trip (which I haven't notice it do), there will then be a Massive Mass Outbreak in the location you were in.

[image: Image of map with Massive Mass Outbreak]

Complete the outbreak collection and you'll be good to go on the quest.

Comment: By sheer coincidence, when I went to head off to the Obsidian Fieldlands to do exactly what you suggested, there was another Massive Mass Outbreak already going on. I've now finished the quest successfully. Thanks for the advice!